# How to get metadata from file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, metadata

For example I have a file '1.mp3', metadata are length, codec, compositor, license, bitrate, etc
How can I get that metadata? I want to get metadata from different types of files.

Comment: What different types? Pictures? Audio?

Comment: Yes, Pictures, Audio, Video, Files etc

Answer (score 1):

For audio formats, have a look at [TagLib Sharp](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp).

Comment: what about, say, Images? TagLib sharp doesnt work on those AFIK

Comment: @Muad'Dib: Originally the question didn't mention images. "different types" could mean just different audio formats...

Comment: true, he didn't say images, but he also didn't specify WHAT kind of files, and DID say "different types of files." he DID use mp3 as an example, tho

Answer (score 1):

The way that you get meta-data depends on the file type. For example, the metadata in an MP3 is stored differently then, say, a JPEG image.